# When is it permitted to make the default constructor private

Tags: c++, constructor

I have two classes, one has permitted making the only explicitly declared constructor, the no arguments one, private. I recently added another class but am getting compile-time errors due to having made the no argument constructor private. The only difference is the first had a public static factory method while the latter has a non-static constructor which takes an argument.

Thanks, hope this makes some sense.

Okay, I give you some code:

This doesn't compile:

```
class GridElem {
public:
    GridElem(const char _idata);
    ~GridElem();
private:
    GridElem();
}
```

This does compile:

```
class GridElem {
public:
    GridElem(const char _idata);
    ~GridElem();
    GridElem();
}
```

This does compile:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    ~MyClass();
private:
    MyClass();
```

Not a complete example, sorry, but I believe this shows where the anomally arises, perhaps from extending `cocos2d::Layer`?

**EDIT**

Alright I found the call that is doing this (eclipse couldn't find it :()

in header

> GridElem myGrid[15][15];

in cpp file

> MyClass::MyClass() : myGrid{0} {}

I only recently changed it from a smaller grid and giving each element explicitly (because it was still just 0 for want of more information), I think this must now expand to parameterless c'tor. I completely forgot that, sorry, but it wasn't 100% obvious mistake.

Comment: when he default constructor is private, you cant use it from the outside

Comment: Without complete code and the error message it doesn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always make the default constructor private (or not have a default constructor at all).

What you can't do is *use* a private default constructor from outside the class (or its friends).

You haven't provided enough context to know for sure, but I suspect your problem is that something else in your code is trying to default construct a `GridElem`, so it needs to be public.

> The only difference is the first had a public static factory method while the latter has a non-static constructor which takes an argument.

If `MyScene` has a factory method then that's a member and can call the private default constructor. There's no "anomaly", you've just said that both types can only be default constructed by their own member functions (and friends), but only one of them has a member function to actually do that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking (which constructor initializer list?! why don't you show the relevant code instead of making people guess?!) but arrays will often use a default constructor.

Comment: i found the only (I think) reference to any `GridElem` c'tor and put it in the OP.

Comment: Yes, `MyGrid{0}` will initialize the first element of the array with `GridElem{0}` and the other 224 elements using the default constructor.

Answer (score -1):

making default constructor private usually means you want all 
creation to go through a factory. So use said factory, or make it public

Comment: What about other constructors?